# Trouble when publishing website in Quarto Pub using VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, quarto

Updated:
This is what I have on my code cell
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgt8V.png)

For python environment,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89D2w.png)

I don't know which one to choose. I found it when I execute the code block, How do I make it for all of my code cells and files?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oArHb.png)

This is where I installed python, I guess: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxBFd.png)

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrY6P.png)
I am trying to publish this website into Quarto Pub.
When rendering on the local host, it worked just fine. But when I ran the code " quarto publish quarto-pub" on the terminal. It generated this error. Please help me. Thank you so much

I added "conda install jupyterlab, jupyternotebook" I tried to add path to the directory, but I don't know if I did it correctly.

Could you help me on publishing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you chosen the correct python kernel?

[image]

I think this was caused by incorrect python kernel and you installed the package in another python environment.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check the terminal? Mine does not show that,  I attached mine  in the updated section of my question.  How do I check which python environment should I install my packages in? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: The jupyter kernel you selected is python 3.10.9. However, in the interface you select python interpreter, it is 3.11 and other virtual environments. You need to ensure that you have not selected the wrong environment. For example, you can select interpreter Python 3.11, install python package in this environment in the terminal, and then modify jupyter kernel to Python 3.11 to maintain consistency.